# Does AngularJS help out in any way when it comes to have a duration counter on my web page?

Tags: angularjs

I have an application that uses Angular ui-router. When the router is set to a certain state I would like to have a timer set to for example 2 hours. While it is set to another state I would like to have the counter count down. I would like to have the time remaining display on my screen.

Does anyone have any code example on how I could go about implementing this functionality? If anyone has done something similar I would appreciate any advice they could give.

Comment: Why do not implement it in controller and redirect back on countdown end

Comment: @MaximShoustin - Yes I hope for something like that but I have not seen any examples. Hopefully someone has already done something like that and they can share what they did.

Comment: Do not do it inside controller. Use `onEnter` in state definition

Comment: Do you want the countdown to reset after refresh or not?

Comment: I would like the counter to maintain the current count if there is a page refresh.

Comment: I've done so. Check my answer...

Comment: @SamanthaJ could you please accept my answer or comment if something is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently using a countdown service for this purpose in my project. as per your requirement you can use service like below :

1. start init it on first page

   ```
   app.controller('view1Ctrl', function($scope, $csCountdown){
     $csCountdown.init(2 * 3600); // 2 hours
     $scope.countdown = $csCountdown.data;
   })
   ```
2. start the counter on second page

   ```
   app.controller('view2Ctrl', function($scope, $csCountdown){
     $csCountdown.start();
     $scope.countdown = $csCountdown.data;
   })
   ```

you can display the value on any page using `countdown.stringValue`

```
<h1>Time : {{countdown.stringValue}}</h1>
```

you can see it working [PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/gZqZNFD7hz6POQIqwm1K?p=preview). I have created view1 & view2 with transition animation.

**EDIT**

I have update the [PLUNKER 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/t106zLNk1QMmgnL9kvmu) to have a practical example.

1. Initially you see instruction page, where timer is initialized to 2 hours.
2. Then move to questions 1, where timer starts
3. from question 1 you can go to help page, where the timer pauses
4. then you move back to question 2, where timer resumes...

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is between the two pages? It seems like the first page is set to two hours and does not change. Would it be possible to hold the value of the countdown after I move to the other page and have it continue when I return to that page?

Comment: @SamanthaJ please checkout the updated plunker, where the countdown service is used in practical scenario... exam simulation.

Comment: Why this is accepted as answer? I don't say it's wrong but it doesn't keep the current count after refresh. Also I've answered way before...

Comment: any reasons for downvote? `but it doesn't keep the current count after refresh` is this the reason? then, this requirement is not mentioned anywhere in question.

Comment: `When should I vote down?`

Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine a service and a directive for this purpose. Service uses cookies to store countdown value. So it'll keep counting even after a refresh.

You can start or stop countdown from controller:

```
CountdownService.startCounting(3 * 30 * 1000); // milliseconds
```

Then show the remaining time from a directive in the template:

```
<countdown></countdown>
```

Also you can change the style of the directive from template.

Check my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Un9TpOEyfnnZ3RHbDSSC?p=preview)...

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am checking into it to see if it meets my needs.

Comment: I don't know if it fits your exact needs or not but I guess you can extend it after this point...

Comment: Hi, I opened up a bounty for this. Hope to see if others have any solutions. If not then I will award the bounty. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, then I guess I can extend this further. Do you see anything wrong or an obvious improvement in my code...